# Displaying a literal period following razor syntax

Tags: html, razor, mvccontrib

How can I escape the razor engine to print a literal period after my property value?  The compiler is interpreting the period as to be followed by a method or property, so it throws an error that 'PDF' is not a valid property or method.

```
col.Custom(@<a href="http://someurl/@item.INSTRUMENT_NUM.pdf">@item.INSTRUMENT_NUM</a>).Named("Instrument Number");
```

### yellow screen of death

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'string' does not contain a definition
>   for 'pdf' and no extension method 'pdf' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrap it in parenthesis (assuming `INSTRUMENT_NUM` is a property of `item` and not to be printed as literal - adapt the closing parenthesis location if this is not the case):

```
col.Custom(@<a href="http://someurl/@(item.INSTRUMENT_NUM).pdf">@item.INSTRUMENT_NUM</a>)
   .Named("Instrument Number");
```