# How to generate "1. Do the homework" from "@Model.Number. @Model.Task" in razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I need to generate a string which looks like `variable, dot, space, another variable`.

The `@Model.Number. @Model.Task` or `@(Model.Number). @(Model.Task)` or `@{Model.Number}. @{Model.Task}` doesn't seem to compile.

The `@Model.Number<text>. </text>@Model.Task` works, but it generates a trashy `<text>` tag in the resulting html.

If I place all of these on a separate line:

```
@Model.Number
. 
@Model.Task
```

then the result will render with an extra space between the number and the dot.

The `@Model.Number@:. @Model.Task` doesn't compile either.

Comment: `@string.Format("{0}. {1}", Model.Number, Model.Task)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying a literal period following razor syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651584/displaying-a-literal-period-following-razor-syntax)

Comment: `@(Model.Number). @Model.Task` does work for me (MVC 5 Razor 3)

Comment: @haim770 Disregard what I said about @() not working, I was just lazy to try everything blindly, sorry. It works, thanks!

Comment: @PeretFinctor Then you should accept this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@(Model.Number). @Model.Task
```

Comment: OP said this didn't work, though I don't entirely believe it.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
@(Model.Number + ". " + Model.Task)
```